# "optional" params in AngularJS states/views with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a customer search view that, by default, simply loads a form for first and last name. It can, however, take those params as arguments in the URL. My app config contains:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state({
            name:        "search",
            url:         "/search",
            templateUrl: "partials/customerSearch.html",
            controller:  "CustomerSearchCtrl"
        })
        .state({
            name:        "searchGiven",
            url:         "/search/:fn/:ln",
            templateUrl: "partials/customerSearch.html",
            controller:  "CustomerSearchCtrl"
        })
```

This works, but it seems like it has unnecessary redundancies. Is there a better way? Is this something `$urlRouterProvider` should handle?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's an [issue in ui-router tracker](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108) about optional parameters. As of now, you can not specify them in clear way, but you can use regular expressions:

```
url: '/search{fn:(?:/[^/]+)?}'
```

or query parameters:

```
url: '/search?fn&ln'
```

People are working on it, though, so I'd expect desired functionality to land sometime in the future.

Comment: The first option doesn't work. For `search/John/Smith` I get `fn=""` and no `ln`. Using query params seems to cause the params to "stick" to the URL in further states/views, which is not acceptable.

Comment: It may be fixed, but it is not on the latest release (0.2.10) as of 6/23/2014.

Comment: v0.2.10. For me fn matches leading / as well. I.e. in /search/123 fn is matched to /123

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
$stateProvider
.state({
    name:        "searchGiven",
    url:         "/search/{fn}/{ln}",
    params: {
        fn: {value: 'foo'},
        ln: {value: 'bar'}
    },
    templateUrl: "partials/customerSearch.html",
    controller:  "CustomerSearchCtrl"
})
```

Comment: It is not optional, even if we don't need to pass anything then `...com/search` will not work but we need to use `...com/search//` which is not good.

Answer (score 3):

There is an update, you can do that:

```
$stateProvider.state("foo", {
  url: "/search/{fn}/{ln}"
});
```

As nateabele commented at the issue about optional parameters: [view here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108#issuecomment-40558474)